# Reading sensor data from UART ESP32 on Windows 10

Tags: esp32, uart, micropython

I am currently trying to get data from a sensor which is connected to the UART ports (GPIO 16 and GPIO 17) of ESP32. I've googled on how to do that but I did not found a proper tutorial on how to do that.
I am using Micropython.

[ESP32 Pinout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaLP0.jpg)

I know that the ESP32 is sending the data bit by bit. I found a website that explains the data transfer in UART. [Here](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/uart-a-hardware-communication-protocol.html#:%7E:text=By%20definition%2C%20UART%20is%20a,going%20to%20the%20receiving%20end.)

But I don't understand on how to get that data from the sensor and translate it into a proper usable data.